# Compiling .scss file with compass individually to specific path

Tags: sass, compass-sass

when I do:

```
compass compile app/css/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss
```

it will compile that file to:

```
app/css/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.css
```

Is there a way to tell compass to compile the file to a specific directory when compiling an single file?  Momething like:

```
compass compile app/css/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss:app/css/bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override any of the Compass [config properties](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/#configuration-properties) via the CLI, so in this case you'd do something like:

```
compass compile app/css/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss --css-dir=app/css
```